# MYSQL binary log file not capturing in slave machine

Tags: mysql, replication

mysql binary log files are not getting captured in slave machine, its available in master machine. When i check the binary log files its of size 1kb without any data in slave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not writing directly on your slave, no binary logs will get generated by default.

To capture the binary log events from the master into the slave's binary log, you need two things:

- enable `log-bin`
- enable [`log_slave_updates`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates)

Comment: The usual suspects (+1)

Comment: log-bin="D:/db/logs/mysql-bin"
log_bin_index="D:/db/logs/mysql-bin.index"
max_binlog_size=512M
sync_binlog=1
#log-error="L:/db/logs/error_log"
#slow-query-log-file = "D:/db/logs/slow_queries"
#long_query_time=1
#log-warnings
expire_logs_days=2
binlog_format=ROW   this is my ini file, can you please tell what changes i have to do.

Comment: `log_slave_updates=1`; then restart.